# Ping: work in one direction only

Tags: ping

I have a Windows LAN (Domain).
Also, 2 Ubuntu machines in the LAN: 22.04 and 20.04.
I do
ping IP 20.04->22.04 : it works fine
When I do
ping IP 22.04->20.04 : no responses.

What can be a reason?

Comment: Are you using the ip address or the hostname to ping? What are the firewall settings set to on both machines: `sudo ufw status verbose`?

Comment: Yes, I do ping by IP. On both machines >sudo ufw status verbose Status: inactive

Comment: I have made >ufw disable, >ufw enable and after it ping works ;-)

Comment: Awesome. You should post this as an answer below. You will be able to mark your answer as the accepted answer after a couple of days, just to give other people a chance to answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the routes, maybe there is a network device which not allow the ping.

Comment: Please more details. What commands to use?

Comment: @ZedZip Like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349703/167115) and also use `traceroute`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked:

```
$sudo ufw status verbose
```

status:inactive
Then I did:

```
$sudo ufw disable
$sudo ufw enable
```

And finally ping works <-> in both directions and also from other windows machines.