# Ubuntu 20.04, Cannot ping gateway

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp, gateway

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Connected to ethernet getting dhcp setting automatic from modem.

Gateway 192.168.2.1
Ubuntu 192.168.2.100
Home device 192.168.2.21

Home device is able to connect to internet no problem.

Ubuntu cannot get online.

Home device can ping ubuntu and receives response successfully.

Home device ping to gateway
Success

Ubuntu ping to home device
Success

Ubuntu ping gateway
Nothing

I have been pouring over documents for days. I have hard reset modem. I have whitelisted the ubuntu.
I have sudo disable ufw
I have tried multiple cables.

I am at a loss.
Please help

The output of `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp6s0 proto metric 20100
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp6s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.100 metric 100
```

The output of `ip address`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc no queue state Unknown group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     Inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state up group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:fe:b5:dd:71:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.100/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp6s0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    Inet6 fe80::2b3c:abc9:52b8:2ffb/64 scope link noprefixroute
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ip route`

Comment: Your default route is set with very low priority ... I don't know if that is the culprit, but try deleting it and adding it again to compare ... `sudo ip route del default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp6s0` and then `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp6s0` ... Also please add ith output of `ip address`

Comment: I've updated to include results of ip address. If anyone can offer some help

Answer (score 0):

After reading other issues similar to mine like this.

[ubuntu 20.04 server not responding to ping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349423/ubuntu-20-04-server-not-responding-to-ping)

I decided to try a new IP address and I have no idea why, but it worked.